# Virtuemart category throws a 500 error

Tags: virtuemart

I am running joomla version 2.5.19 and virtuemart version 2.6.0.

The site was working just fine until recently i noticed when i visit a specific category, it throws a 500 error. That is in the front end.

I also get the same error if i visit the that particular category in the back end as well. I checked my server log files and i noticed there was an error that said something like this;

> 2015-12-01 08:14:37 ERROR vmError: related product is missing, maybe unpublished Yoga Wrap id: 36

I am thinking it could be some missing or inaccurate data in that particular category. How can i fix this?

Alternatively, how can i delete this products in that particular category via phpmyadmin?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, @Joey. Please upgrade to Joomla 2.5.28 and VM 2.6.14 (or consider using VirtueMart 3). For security reasons it's very important to run the latest available software. Make sure you take a [backup](http://akeebabackup.com) before updating :)

Comment: Joey, @johanpw recommendation is important - first you need to run up-to-date software. Keep in mind though, that updating doesn't necessarily mean that your specific issue will be solved. But generally you can't expect much of help when using outdated, unsupported and even worse (for you and the world) insecure software.

Comment: Welcome to JSE @Joey. My strong recommendation is to make the move to VM 3 - install on an updated J2.5.28 test version of the site first. VM3 does work with J2.5.28 http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=126862.0 as Kelvyn explains on this page, however I would also recommend you take the opp to update J2.5 to J3 since it's been over a year and most VM plugins have been updated for J3, and of course J3 is a much improved version of Joomla.

Comment: Thank you all for the warm welcome and recommendations. I did manage to update my Joomla and VM last night but on a test environment.

I am running Joomla version 3 and virtuemart version 3 as well. That is great. However, the error is still there :-( 

How do i delete/debug/solve this problem? Note the error is only in two categories and i suspect some tables/data are somehow corrupted which hinders me from accessing those categories in VM backend.

Comment: Are you reaching the offending cats through a menu item? If so, rebuild your menus.
No luck? Make sure Joomla debug is off, and then turn on vmdebug. See if that throws any light on the subject. If nothing else works, I'd consider backing up your DB and using the VM tools to update the database (last resort as this can throw up other issues).

Comment: @garth yes, i am accessing the category via a menu item. I have tried rebuilding the menu but as long i set it to fetch products from that category, it still throws the error. Like i said, seems like that particular category has products that are not correctly inserted and or it's database is corrupted. 

How do i delete these products via phpmyadmin?

This seems like the only option after which i will have to recreate that category and insert products again ensuring they don't break the site. 
Anyone who understands the VM table structure would be able to a advice.

Comment: @Joeyngethe if there aren't too many have you tried disabling the products in that category and seeing if the error goes away. Can't you delete them via Virtuemart admin, or are there too many?

Comment: @garth when i log in to the VM admin panel and go to that specific category, i get a 500 error. So deleting from the admin is not an option and that is why i am asking if anyone knows the exact tables i need to delete from the phpmyadmin area. I hope you get me now?